# Can you initialize Html.TextBoxFor with a value in localStorage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, local-storage, html.textboxfor

Can you initialize the value of Html.TextBoxFor with a value in HTML5 localStorage?

I know that you can initiliaze with a string.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.name, new {@Value="John Doe"})
```

What if I want to use a string in localStorage instead of "John Doe"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant, you would have to use javascript, or create a helper which outputs the javascript for you.

if you create the helper you can use jquery:

```
var localStorageKey = "yourkey";
$("#textboxid").val(window.localStorage[localStorageKey]);
```